# pass a variable into a ascii art

Tags: bash, cat

In bash/ Ubuntu,

If there is a ASCII art file: "ascii-art" in the following

```
 |__   __|  ____|/ ____|__   __|
    | |  | |__  | (___    | |   
    | |  |  __|  \___ \   | |   
    | |  | |____ ____) |  | |   
    |_|  |______|_____/   |_|   Client ${CLIENT_ID}
```

Is there anyway to pass the variable "${CLIENT_ID}" into the ascii-art every time we call it?

The way we call it at the moment:

```
cat ascii-art
```

The following ways don't work

```
1.  cat ascii-art | CLIENT_ID="1"
```

or

2. Add one more line in the first line of the file "ascii-art"

> ```
> . command_line_parse.sh -c ${CLIENT_ID}
>
>  |__   __|  ____|/ ____|__   __|
>     | |  | |__  | (___    | |   
>     | |  |  __|  \___ \   | |   
>     | |  | |____ ____) |  | |   
>     |_|  |______|_____/   |_|   Client ${CLIENT_ID}
> ```

Then

```
cat ascii-art | CLIENT_ID="1"
```

Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks.

Comment: You aren't "calling" anything; it's not a script. Bash variables do not make a sound platform for a templating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: look at the programs `figlet`, `toilet` or `cowasy`. These are probably finished implementation of what you want.

If you want to write it yourself:

```
sed 's/${CLIENT_ID}/42/g' ascii-art
```

Comment: Is it possible that we make the "42" here as a variable input ? At moment if I do sed 's/${CLIENT_ID}/${CLIENT_ID_INPUT}/g' ascii-art, it will replace the  "${CLIENT_ID}" with "${CLIENT_ID_INPUT}"

Comment: Use " instead of ' and read some tutorial about Linux shell quoting. Don't forget to mark my post as answer if it works.

Answer (score 2):

The `envsubst` tool is written for exactly this purpose:

```
CLIENT_ID=foo envsubst ascii-art
```

This is a preferable tool to `sed`, which restricts the range of possible values (if you had a `/` in your id, or even worse a semicolon followed by another `sed` command, serious bugs could ensue).

---

See also [TemplateFiles](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/TemplateFiles) on the Wooledge wiki, which includes a native-bash implementation for systems without GNU gettext (which includes `envsubst`).

Answer (score 1):

The following evaluates the `echo` command for the contents of the file:

```
CLIENT_ID=1000 eval "$(cat <<EOC
echo -e "$(<ascii-art)"
EOC
)"
```

- `CLIENT_ID=1000` assigns environment variable for the `eval` command
- `eval` accepts a here document as its single argument
- `$(<ascii-art)`, in Bash, does the same as `$(cat ascii-art)`

*EDIT regarding the scary `eval`*

It's true that we should avoid using `eval`. But we should also understand the
purpose of the command and do use it when appropriate. We should understand
the security risks, and decide whether we should, or we shouldn't use `eval`
in certain situations.

The [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/eval) gives a good description
of `eval`:

> Perhaps the easiest way to think about eval is that it works in the same way
>   as running `bash -c "bash code…"` from a script, except in the case of
>   `eval`, the given code is executed in the current shell environment rather
>   than a child process.

So `eval` just executes the shell code we pass. How often we execute
external commands from Bash scripts? I guess, quite often. And the commands
are just trusted executables which may well be Bash scripts themselves.

Then why should one be scared of evaluating some `echo "trusted content"`?

It is up to the user(OP) to decide whether it is safe to use `eval` in certain
situation. However, this answer definitely gives him an option; it is an
alternate solution. So I don't understand the downvote on this answer.

Comment: This seems like a very bad idea unless you know the contents of both `CLIENT_ID` and the file before hand.

Comment: @chepner, well, the OP seems to know both. The file is obviously private. Any good ideas, btw?

Comment: If the value of `CLIENT_ID` were fixed, there'd be no need to templatize the location into which it's being substituted. Since it's not fixed, assuming an attacker will never be able to manipulate the substituted value is dangerous: One of the first goals of someone breaking into a system is figuring out how to escalate that access. If this is (say) a prompt printed to a user who just connected before putting them into a very restricted shell, any bug that gave them control over `CLIENT_ID` could be levered into a way around those restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

Modified from RotatingPieces' answer above

First modify the "ascii-art" file, and change "${CLIENT_ID}" into "CLIENT_ID_ART"

```
 |__   __|  ____|/ ____|__   __|
    | |  | |__  | (___    | |   
    | |  |  __|  \___ \   | |   
    | |  | |____ ____) |  | |   
    |_|  |______|_____/   |_|   Client CLIENT_ID_ART
```

Now the following approach might not be very elegant, but it works perfectly

```
CLIENT_ID="1" # The ${CLIENT_ID} will actually be from the command line parser

echo "sed 's/CLIENT_ID_ART/"${CLIENT_ID}"/g' ascii-art > call_art

chmod +x call_art

./call_art &

rm -f call_art
```

The above will print out the following in the output

```
 |__   __|  ____|/ ____|__   __|
    | |  | |__  | (___    | |   
    | |  |  __|  \___ \   | |   
    | |  | |____ ____) |  | |   
    |_|  |______|_____/   |_|   Client 1
```